# Bash script interpreter that runs in JVM (Jbash?)

Tags: bash, jvm-languages

I'm wondering if there exists a bash shell script interpreter that runs solely in the JVM (i.e., does *not* rely on "shelling out" to a system bash.)  A "Jbash" if you will.

Such interpreters exist for many other languages (JRuby, Jython, etc.)  I'd have thought there'd be one for bash scripts as well but I haven't found one yet.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one in google code http://code.google.com/p/jbash/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this one is currently buggy, simple `ls` and `pwd` commands throw ParseExceptions.

Comment: Yes, this project seems dead. Yet such a shell would be a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new project : https://github.com/crashub/bash but too young at the moment:

> Very early prototype built on top of the libbash ANTLR grammar, aims
>   to implement basic stuff. The grammar provides an AST.